# LINQ to SQL grouping multiple columns with a distinct row

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have the following table structure. I want to select distinct `CustomerId` and `CustomerName`, `TotalCost`.

Here's the table structure and column data type.

```
LogId (int)
CustomerId (string)
CustomerName (string)
Cost (int)
```

> Logid / CustomerId / CustomerName / Cost

- 1 2031 John Steward 20
- 2 2035 Mary Joe          10
- 3 2034 Robert Tuck 30
- 4 2031 John Setward 12
- 5 2036 Luke David 15
- 6 2033 Kevin Le 14
- 7 2035 Mary Joe 9
- 8 2036 Luke David 8
- 9 2035 Mary Joe 18
- 10 2037 Jesse Tom 25
- 11 2032 Antony James 27
- 12 2033 Kevin Le 26

> Update 1

Here's my attempted query so far:

```
Dim db As New DemoDataContext()

    Dim query = From log In db.LogRecords _
                 Where log.Cost> 10 _
                 Group log By New With {log.CustomerId, log.CustomerName} Into g() _
                 Select New With {g.CustomerId, g.CustomerName, .Cost = g.Sum(Function(log) log.Cost)}
```

But it makes error message **Range variable name can be inferred only from a simple or qualified name with no arguments.**

> Update 2

```
Dim queryResult = (From log In db.LogRecords _ 
    Group log By log.CustomerId, log.CustomerName Into Cost = Sum(log => log.Cost ) _ 
    Select New With { CustomerId, CustomerName, TotalCost })

For Each q In queryResult

Next
```

**Error : Name 'queryResult' is not declared.**

Comment: Ok.. so you want to select CustomerId, CustomerName and TotalCost or LogId, CoustomerId and TotalCost?

Comment: I want to select CustimerId,CustomerName, and their total cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, something like this should work in C#:

```
var query = from row in dataTable
            group row by new { row.CustomerId, row.CustomerName } into g
            select new
            {
                g.Key.CustomerId,
                g.Key.CustomerName,
                Cost = g.Sum(row => row.Cost)
            };
```

[edit]

I guess my initial thought on why it didn't work was wrong.  We just had wrong syntax.

```
Dim query = From log In db.LogRecords                     _
            Group log By log.CustomerId, log.CustomerName _
                Into Cost = Sum(log => log.Cost)          _
            Select CustomerId, CustomerName, Cost
```

Comment: Sorry, this is where my level of familiarity with VB ends.  I don't know what the proper syntax is for LINQ queries in VB and can't find any relevant examples anywhere.  There are so many different styles in all the examples I could find.

Comment: Just so you know, I noticed you can leave out the "New With" part and just list the fields the projection should have.  i.e., `Select CustomerID, CustomerName, TotalCost`

Answer (score 3):

Just an observation. According to what Jeff M wrote and update in the question.

```
 Dim queryResult = (From log In db.LogRecords_
            Where log.Cost > 10 _
            Group log By log.CustomerId, log.CustomerName Into Cost = Sum(log.Cost) _
            Select New With {CustomerId, CustomerName, Cost})
```

Comment: Ah thanks, looks like my test code is working too.  Wait, I see it now, different field names.