# LINQ-ing with an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to using LINQ. I am trying to use it in Silverlight as I'm trying to do a DISTINCT query. My Silverlight application pings a WCF service which returns an ObservableCollection of a custom type. I am trying to get to a DISTINCT record set based on several properties of my custom type. I know the first step is to get my record set, so I'm trying the following

```
var filteredItems = (from entity in e.Result
                    select new FilteredItem
                    {
                      Property1 = entity.Property1,
                      Property2 = entity.Property2,
                      Property3 = entity.Property3
                    }).Distinct();
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Intellisense gives me an error that says "*Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type MyServiceProxy.MyCustomType. Select not found...*" How can I use an ObservableCollection with LINQ, or get this distinct set like I'm showing?

Thank you!

Comment: To debug, I would set something before this line to check what e.Result is.  Something like Console.WriteLine(e.Result.GetType().ToString());  See if it is giving you what you expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so you should be able to do that if you're `using System.Linq`. All the standard LINQ operators reside in that namespace. If that doesn't work, then make sure you're referencing System.Core.dll, because that's the assembly that contains those same implementations.

Comment: Doh! I had the System.LINQ namespace removed. Placed it back in and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Getting a distinct list with LINQ is as simple as using the Distinct() method.  You have to use grouping.  Take a look at this:

[LINQ to SQL grouping multiple columns with a distinct row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437622/linq-to-sql-grouping-multiple-columns-with-a-distinct-row)

Answer (score 0):

You need my [ObservableComputations](https://github.com/IgorBuchelnikov/ObservableComputations) library maybe. Using this library you can code like this:

```C#
var filteredItems = e.Result.Selecting(entity => 
                    new FilteredItem
                    {
                      Property1 = entity.Property1,
                      Property2 = entity.Property2,
                      Property3 = entity.Property3
                    }).Distinct();
```

In code above I assumed e.Result is [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8). filteredItems is [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) and reflects all the changes in the e.Result collection and properties mentioned in the code above. Ensure that all properties mentioned in the code above notify of changes through the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) interface.